# Скрытый тулбар и ошибки binding

Tags: c#, wpf, toolbar

У меня есть следующий xaml:

```
<ToolbarTray Visibility="{Binding SomeProperty}">
     <Toolbar>
        <Checkbox IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}/"
      </Toolbar>
</Toolbar>
```

and two classes as possible data context - for two different windows.

```
class ToolbarContextOne 
{
   public Visibility SomeProperty {get;set;} 
}
class ToolbarContextTwo:ToolbarContextOne
{
   public bool IsEnabled {get;set;}
}
```

Я использую тулбар из примера в нескольких ситуациях. Для того, чтобы показывать различные данные в разных окнах, я использую разные дата контексты.
Когда мне не нужна вышеупомянутая секция, я просто ставлю SomeProperty в Visibility.Collapsed. Но всё равно получаю binding error для свойства IsEnabled. Очевидно, парсер пытается выполнить все binding expressions. Есть способ заставить его не выполнять эти выражения в скрытой секции xaml?

Comment: binding error некритичны, проблема то в чём?

Comment: В основном в том, что аутпут засоряется, коллеги жалуются

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное, более чистый путь через `DataTemplate`.

Положите где-нибудь в ресурсы (например, глобальные, или локально в окно, или в `UserControl`) такое:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ToolbarContextOne}">
    <ToolbarTray Visibility="{Binding SomeProperty}">
        <Toolbar>
            <Checkbox IsEnabled="False"/>
        </Toolbar>
    </Toolbar>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ToolbarContextTwo}">
    <ToolbarTray Visibility="{Binding SomeProperty}">
        <Toolbar>
            <Checkbox IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
        </Toolbar>
    </Toolbar>
</DataTemplate>
```

Ну и в том месте, где у вас был `ToolbarTray`, просто

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
```

При этом `ContentPresenter` найдёт нужный `DataTemplate` и использует его.

Comment: Да, оно. Я как-то забыл про этот путь, давненько не писал клиентский код. Спасибо

Comment: @AntonShakalo: Пожалуйста!